# Create game map with Blender

Tags: scripting, export

I'm developing an web-based 3d RPG game using HTML5 technology stack. 
I'm trying to use Blender as much as it possible in my project. I'm using it to create models, landscape meshes, to draw blend maps for landscape textures and so on. Now I'm thinking about how can I use blender to make maps. I can't just put objects and export whole scene. I will have some objects repeated many times over level so I just need information about objects coordinates, rotation, scaling and some custom properties  (like class name from my framework).

So my question is - what options do I have to make this with Blender?
Currently all I can think of is to write a custom plugin for blender to export map in wanted format.

Comment: What do you mean by "HTML5 technology stack"? Seems like Blend4Web would be a better suited platform for this, based on your description. But maybe I'm not completely understanding what you want to do...

Comment: @Mentalist I'm using three.js and self written framework above it.

Comment: You want object instances in the save format and currently none of the existing exporters support that. But hey, you are the guy that makes the framework and Blender can be scripted to export anything so you should have no problem building the pipeline. I would suggest checking if you can find an existing XML exporter frame to start expanding on.

Answer (score -2):

In the obj exporter there is the option

> Objects as OBJ groups

If this is checked it will maintain separate objects in the scene as well as their transforms in world space.

Comment: seems like this does not work as wanted  - https://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/70ae62d70463e28d4bb1ff18931124c0.png

Comment: I put few cubes and then exported them using obj export and `Objects as OBJ groups` was selected by default but still I have vertices information for each mesh, instead of just coordinates/rotation/scale

Comment: If you don’t want vertex data why are you trying to export an object with mesh data?

Comment: If Obj is not what you are looking for check out FBX. Use the binary format, it has an option for saving custom property’s. The custom property’s is saves are the ones under the vertex tab in the property’s window. It will not save custom property’s from any other location unfortunatly.